# 2d game physics, doing it right

Tags: android, 2d, physics

I have a sneaking suspicion I'm doing this wrong. It works now, to the extend that gravity pulls the object down toward the ground, but I'm having trouble manipulating the speed of the object.

What this is, is a ball jumping and falling towards the ground.

I have another function called "jump" that just adds `jSpeed` to it's yVel

I can increase `gravity`, and it falls faster.

I can increase the `jSpeed` speed, and it'll rise up longer, but not faster

But I can't get it to do *everything* faster. It just looks painfully slow, which may or may not be because of my emulator running at 11 fps, on average.

Is it just my emulator, or is it something on my end?

```
float time = elapsedTime/1000F;
if (speed < maxSpeed){
    speed = speed + accel;
}
if(mY + mVelY < Panel.mHeight){ //0,0 is top-left
    mVelY += (speed);
}

if (!(mY + height >= Panel.mHeight)){
    mVelY = mVelY  + gravity ;
}

mX  =  (float) (mX +(mVelX * time));
mY =  (float) (mY + (mVelY * time));
```

Comment: How often do you call this piece of code? Do you keep track of elapsed time since last call? Also, not related to your question, but: `speed = speed + accel;` -> `speed` can be greater than `maxSpeed`.

Comment: @Gabriel This code is called every frame, and elapsed time is being tracked. It's using `System.currentTimeMilis();` I updated the code in my question to show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the right general ideas here but a lot about your code is confusing.

My issues are mostly about the variable speed - it seems to me that your ball is being accelerated up by the variables speed and accel until reaching a maximum speed. Opposing this is gravity pulling (accelerating) the ball down.

Now typically this isn't how a 'jump' the way you describe it is. So for me when the player hits 'jump' you should set the YVel to jspeed and just let the gravity part of the equation bring it back down - that is if you deleted the code:

```
if(mY + mVelY < Panel.mHeight){ //0,0 is top-left
  mVelY += (speed);
}
```

Then it would go up for a bit and then loose momentum to the gravity and come back down - where as this code above keeps pushing it upwards until it hits the top, and as soon as it starts descending pushes it back up.

I wonder if the code around speed and maxspeed is supposed to act on XVel and not YVel as you have coded - that would make more sense.

Comment: I think it did act on XVel once, and it had something to do with friction. Thanks for pointing that out, though.

Comment: Actually, that may have fixed my problem. Now, if I want it to go faster, I think I can just increase the gravity, relative to the jumping speed.  It still just looks slow on my emulator, because of the 11 fps thing

Comment: The emulator fps shouldn't affect the speed of the fall - just make it look more jumpy - please accept this response if I helped you.